# Gitlab error : The requested URL returned error: 403

Tags: git, gitlab

I tried to pull to Gitlab but it's not working.

When i tried push, (Commit, Initialize, add worked well)

Error says remote : You are not allowed to push code to this project.
fatal: unable to access 'http://IPADDRESS/username/GitProjectName/': The requested URL returned error : 403

When i try to push in other computer, it works.

Any suggestion??

Comment: How do you authenticate with your server? Also, `http://` confuses me. AFAIK Git can only push via SSH or HTTPS

Comment: The address I meant, clone with http part when you make project. Should i use SSH?

Comment: You can copy the correct clone/push URL from the project settings in GitLab.

Comment: oh that address is my company address.  The address you meant was right. should i authenticate server?

Comment: If you're working on Windows, your Windows Credential Manager might have stored an old password of yours on that server. Open the Credential Manager and look under "Windows Credentials" for a line referring to that GitLab server. If you find it, either delete it to get prompted again for your password at the next Git push or pull operation, or edit it with your current credentials.

Comment: If you're working on another OS, the same principle applies, you might have stale credentials stored in whatever credential manager is active on your machine.

Comment: @knittl: Git supports http (in addition to https) but it's generally not recommended due to lack-of-security. Git*Hub* do not support it, but in a private installation (of GitHub Enterprise or GitLab or whatever), the admins can do whatever they want.

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me under the following circumstances:

I deleted (completely) a project at Gitlab called "ProjectX".

I then tried to create a new project with this name "ProjectX" by doing this:

```
.../project_x$ git push --set-upstream https://gitlab.com/mrodent/ProjectX.git master
Username for 'https://gitlab.com': mrodent
Password for 'https://mrodent@gitlab.com': 
remote: You are not allowed to push code to this project.
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/mrodent/ProjectX.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

... but when I then tried to create a project with name "ProjectX2" ... it worked.

My assumption is that GitLab hasn't actually yet wiped this pre-existing project from its system. Which is a bit annoying. I shall wait 24 h and try again.